# Induction in proof of Rule of Substitution

Tags: logic, induction

From "An Introduction to Mathematical Logic and Type Theory: To Truth Through Proof" by Peter B. Andrews:

---

1101 Rule of Substitution (Sub). If $\mathcal{H} \vdash A$, and if $p_{1}, \ldots, p_{n}$ are distinct variables which do not occur in any wff in $\mathcal{H}$, then $\mathcal{H} \vdash S_{B_{1} \ldots B_{n}}^{p_{1} \ldots p_{n}} A$.

Proof: Let $\theta$ be the substitution $S_{B_{1} \ldots B_{n}}^{p_{1} \ldots p_{n}}$. It is easy to see that if $C_{1}, \ldots, C_{m}$ is a proof of $A$ from $\mathcal{H}$, then $\theta C_{1}, \ldots, \theta C_{m}$ is a proof of $\theta A$ from $\mathcal{H}$. Note how the condition on the variables comes into play when $C_{i}$ is a member of $\mathcal{H}$.

Of course, the sentence above is really a rather brief sketch of a proof of this metatheorem. For a more complete proof, show by complete induction on $i$ that $\mathcal{H} \vdash \theta C_{i}$ for each $i$ with $1 \leq i \leq m$. Break the proof into cases according to how $C_{i}$ was justfied in the original proof.

---

I am confused as to why induction is necessary for this proof. It seems that since we have shown the case for an arbitrary natural number $m$, that it holds for all natural numbers $m$. If I expand the given proof:

Proof: Let $m$ be any natural number. Suppose that $C_{1}, \ldots, C_{m}$ is a proof from $\mathcal{H}$. We will show that $\theta C_{1}, \ldots, \theta C_{m}$ is a proof from $\mathcal{H}$. Let $j$ be any natural number such that $1 \leq j \leq m$. Then either (1) $C_{j}$ is an axiom, (2) $C_{j}$ is a member of $\mathcal{H}$, or (3) there exist $i < j$ and $k < j$ such that $C_{k}$ is $[C_{i} \to C_{j}]$. Suppose $C_{j}$ is an axiom. Then $\theta C_{j}$ is an axiom. Suppose $C_{j}$ is a member of $\mathcal{H}$. Then $\theta C_{j} = C_{j}$ and hence $\theta C_{j}$ is a member of $\mathcal{H}$. Suppose there exist $i < j$ and $k < j$ such that $C_{k}$ is $[C_{i} \to C_{j}]$. Then $\theta C_{k} = \theta [C_{i} \to C_{j}] = [\theta C_{i} \to \theta C_{j}]$. Hence there exist $i < j$ and $k < j$ such that $\theta C_{k}$ is $[\theta C_{i} \to \theta C_{j}]$. Hence $\theta C_{1}, \ldots, \theta C_{m}$ is a proof from $\mathcal{H}$.

Then suppose $\mathcal{H} \vdash A$. Then for some natural number $m$ there is a proof $C_{1}, \ldots, C_{m}$ of $A$ from $\mathcal{H}$. Then $\theta C_{1}, \ldots, \theta C_{m}$ is a proof of $\theta A$ from $\mathcal{H}$. Hence $\mathcal{H} \vdash \theta A$.

EDIT:

The text also states: A proof of a wff $B$ from the set $\mathcal{H}$ of hypotheses is a finite sequence $B_{1}, \ldots, B_{m}$ of wffs such that $B_{m}$ is $B$ and for each $j$ $(1 \leq j \leq m)$ at least one of the following conditions is satisfied: (1) $B_{j}$ is an axiom. (2) $B_{j}$ is a member of $\mathcal{H}$. (3) $B_{j}$ is inferred by Modus Ponens from wffs $B_{i}$ and $B_{k}$, where $i < j$ and $k < j$. An alternative way of expressing condition (3) is to say that there exist $i < j$ and $k < j$ such that $B_{k}$ is $[B_{i} \to B_{j}]$.

Comment: The author actually gives two methods for proving the theorem, one by induction and one using the formation sequence definition of proof. You elaborated the sequence version, which does not require induction because the objects of study already have the induction "baked in" so to speak. The alternate characterization takes $\mathcal{H}\vdash$ to be the least relation containing the axioms, such that $\mathcal{H}\vdash A$ and $\mathcal{H}\vdash A\to B$ implies $\mathcal{H}\vdash B$. With this definition an inductive proof is natural (and simpler to some extent than the sequence version).

Comment: @MarioCarneiro I see. I got the impression from "for a more complete proof" that what he had given was lacking and that induction was required to complete it. This has gotten me thinking about whether induction is required in other metatheorems, like the deduction theorem, as well.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro I emailed the author to be certain and it turns out that he believes that any rigorous proof of this metatheorem will involve some form of induction.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro What would it take to formally prove the sequence version? Is it likely that this is already done?

Comment: I don't think stressing about whether the proof uses induction or not is relevant. You gave a proof (the sequence proof as I put it), and it's perfectly fine as it is, and that's all that matters. Unless you mean something else by formal proof...

Comment: @MarioCarneiro I'm just concerned that the author and I have a different understanding and that he has not responded to the proof that I gave without induction. I thought that maybe if I gave a formal proof he might respond, or at least I would have the confidence to move on. It is kind of depressingly circular that I am studying logic so that I can learn how to use formal verification software to check my proofs and avoid these kinds of misunderstandings.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro If the proof I gave is correct, it seems that a lot of the metalogical proofs that use induction, like the deduction theorem, could also be given without induction. Is that true?

Comment: It's possible, but also irrelevant like I said. What matters is if there is a proof of those theorems, and there is, although the exact form of the proof depends on the initial definitions. Not everyone uses this sequence based definition; I would say that it is easier to prove this by induction than by the index manipulation stuff in the sequence definition. But it really doesn't matter.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro I am actually a little bit confused as to how to prove this using induction. If the principle of complete induction is stated as $\forall n [(\forall j < n)R(j) \to R(n)] \to \forall n R(n)$, what would the property $R$ be in the proof the author is suggesting?

Comment: With the definition I gave in my first comment, the induction principle is given by the definition itself - if $P(A)$ is a property of wffs such that $P(A)$ is true if $A$ is an axiom, and if $P(A)$ and $P(A\to B)$ then $P(B)$, then $\mathcal{H}\vdash A$ implies $P(A)$. It should be clear that you can use this principle to prove the substitution theorem, taking $P(A)\equiv \mathcal{H}\vdash \theta A$.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro When you say "alternate characterization" in your first comment, do you mean a different definition of $\mathcal{H} \vdash$ then the author gives? So the proof you are alluding to is a different proof then what the author is saying should be done using complete induction?

Comment: Yes, but the two definitions are provably equivalent so my characterization is a theorem given the author's definition. I don't know what exactly the author is alluding to, but the substitution theorem can be proven in several ways, many of which have been elaborated here.

Comment: I see. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

In (3) you are forgetting an important thing: the formula $C_i$ must  either be an axiom, an hypothesis in $\mathcal H$ or an already proven proposition, that is that $C_1,\dots,C_i$ is a valid proof.

Hence in order to prove that the sequence $\theta C_1,\dots, \theta C_n$ is the valid proof you have to prove inductively that for all those $C_i$'s that are neither axioms or hypotheses the sequence $\theta C_1,\dots,\theta C_i$ is a valid proof.

**Edit**: I have noticed that the OP has added the definition of proof.  According to this definition the argument without induction seems correct. Do not be that surprise by that, it may happen that sometimes authors suggested proofs may be moe complex than they actually need to be, after all we are all humans.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm sorry, I'm still not certain. This seems somewhat different than the definition of a proof as given by the text. I have added that definition to the question.

Comment: @user695931useI have add a little comment in the answer :-)

Comment: @user695931user keep me posted, now I'm interested in what  he/she has to say.

Comment: I emailed the author to be certain and it turns out that he believes that any rigorous proof of this metatheorem will involve some form of induction.

Comment: @user695931 Did he provide any argument?

Comment: I emailed him my attempt at a proof, but I haven't gotten a reply yet.